include error detected on vscode header file what should I do?
#ifndef SYMNMF_H_
#define SYMNMF_H_

void symc (double **, double **,int,int);
void ddgc (double **, double **,int);
void normc (double **,double **,double **,int);
void symnmfc(double **, double **, int,int,double,int);
#endif

im just trying to build a header file with functions from main and I get this: #include errors detected. Please update your includePath.
ive tried everything I saw online and nothing is working.
im on macOS and vscode.
ive tried installing and reinstalling Xcode and it didn't work. also tried a bunch of stuff that I can't even remember I would really appreciate any help right now.
the exact error: #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit

"trying to build a header file" -- one doesn't normally build header files. Header files are meant to be included in other types of source files and the set of source files and header files (and evetually other support files) is used to build an executable, an object file, a library, ...

Do you have a compile error or an Intellisense error? This is one of the few cases where a screenshot of the error might be helpful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Following the instructions here may also help. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

In C language, standard library headers are included using <> like this:
#include <stdio.h>
But, for other library headers like gtk, double-quotes are used:
#include "gtk.h"
I am a layman. I am just sharing what I understood. Hope it works!
